# Two different arrays feeding one subroutine produced RTE-13 'Type Mismatch' with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is a small example of my problem
I have two buttons I push to run an analysis.
Button 1 has a list of 4 people
Button 2 has a list of 3 animals
I cannot mix the lists or my analysis will have errors.

Previously, I had good code. 
When I needed to change things it was getting hard to maintain.
I moved it into subroutines for good configuration management.
Unfortunately, I have difficulty passing certain variables between subroutines

After doing some research I succeeded in making several variables public. The Variant seems to be special. Any suggestions?

```
Public thisList As Variant 
Public xlEvalSheet As Worksheet

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    thisList(1) = "Bobby"
    thisList(2) = "Jane"
    thisList(3) = "Lord Winter"
    thisList(4) = "Jose"
Call DoStuff
EndSub

Sub CommandButton2_Click
    thisList(1) = "Fluffy"
    thisList(2) = "Fido"
    thisList(3) = "Dog"
Call DoStuff
End Sub

Sub DoStuff()
    Dim k Ks Variant
    Dim counterTemple as Integer
    Dim evalTables (0 to 3) as Variant
evalTables(0)= "EvalTable1.xlsx"
evalTables(1)= "EvalTable2.xlsx"
evalTables(2)= "EvalTable3.xlsx"
evalTables(3)= "EvalTable4.xlsx"
    For Each doIt in evalTables
    strEvalTable = NetworkLocation & doIt
        counterTemple = 3 ' used inside the wdUpdateDataInText 

        For Each k In thisList
        controlThis = k & "-" & counterTemple  'passes a string to the wdApp.contentcontrol
            xlEvalSheet.Rows.Hidden = False
            xlEvalSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = k  'initialize k
            xlEvalSheet.Calculate
            DoEvents
                Call wdUpdateDataInText 'this feeds data to MS Word ContentControls

            currentDifference = xlEvalSheet.Cells(5, 6).Value  'stop blank tables from being produced
            If currentDifference = 0 Then  
                Else
                Call PDFcrate 'produces tables as PDFs with FixedFormatExport 
            End If
         Next  'repeats for each tab with name "k" in the workbooks
     xlEval.Close
     counterTemple = counterTemple + 1
    next
End Sub`
```

Comment: I failed to dimension doIt as  variant in the above example. The code had to be changed sorry.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Don't use globals to pass values between different methods - this is what parameters are for.  Unnecessary globals quickly lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use globals to pass values between different methods - this is what parameters are for. Unnecessary globals quickly lead to problems.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    DoStuff Array("Bobby","Jane","Lord Winter","Jose")
EndSub

Sub CommandButton2_Click
    DoStuff Array("Fluffy", "Fido", "Dog")
End Sub

Sub DoStuff(thisList As Variant)

   'use thisList

End sub
```

Comment: The above was very helpful in getting past the RTE-13 issue.

Comment: 'Sub wdUpdateDataInText()

Dim cc As Word.ContentControls ' As Object if late-binding is used
Dim evalData(0 To 2) As Variant 'changed to 2 and linked tables by hand
evalData(0) = " bidder"
evalData(1) = " GTEP"
evalData(2) = " delta"
'evalData(3) = " TABLE"

Dim j As Variant
Dim i As Integer
i = 4
    For Each j In evalData
        With Word.Application.Documents(wdDocReport)
        .SelectContentControlsByTitle(ControlThis & j).Item(1).Range.Text = xlEvalSheet.Cells(5, i).Value
        .Save
        End With
    Next
End Sub'

Comment: Now I am receiving a compile error: Argument not found.   the debugger highlights the 'Sub doStuff(ContractLineItemNumber As Variant)'  It seems that the 'doStuff Array("a", "b", "c")' may not be doing what we want...

Comment: Please update your question if you want to add information - I can't read your code in a comment...